# How whatsapp edited the system share method?

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

I have an simple question, how Whatsapp developers did that:

[image: Whatsapp share]
(What do we see? A normal image share from my gallery, I can share it instantly with 8 contacts from Whatsapp...)

I never saw it before, 
Can I do the same in my own application? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the *Direct Share* feature that was [introduced with Marshmallow](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/09/new-android-marshmallow-sample-apps.html). You can find an [example application in the Google Repository](http://developer.android.com/samples/DirectShare/index.html).

> To enable Direct Share, apps need to implement a Service extending
>   [ChooserTargetService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/chooser/ChooserTargetService.html). Override the method onGetChooserTargets() and
>   return a list of Direct Share options.
>
> In your AndroidManifest.xml, add a meta-data tag in your Activity that
>   receives the Intent. Specify android:name as
>   android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service, and point the
>   android:value to the Service.